# responsive textbox

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, textbox, viewport

I would like some help with my website, i am trying to make the website responsive and i want the 'text box' to remain in place while changing the viewport but at the moment when the viewport shrinks the textbox is no longer in sync, if that makes sense.

Thanks in advance!

```css
body {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
 
}

.body1 {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 72.6vw;
    height: 80vw;
    max-width: 72.6vw;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top:0px;
    max-font-size:16px; 
 margin-left: 23.4vw;
 position:relative;
 bottom:200px;
 padding: 5px 5px;
    
}

    
.webheadimg {
width:96vw;
height:auto;
    max-width:96vw;
    max-height:auto;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    overflow:hidden;
margin-left:1vw;

    }    
#menu {
    width: 21.4vw;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1vw;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 1vw;
    background-color: #CA2A2A;
        border-radius: 0px;
        max-width: 96vw;
    
}
#menu ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 0.5vw 0vw;
    margin: 0px;
}
#menu li { 
    display: block; 

}
#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0.5vw 0.5vw 0.5vw 0.5vw;
 font-size: 3vw;
 display:block;
    
}
#menu a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;

}
.webheadlogo {
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;
margin-left: 1vw;
float:left;
height: auto;
width: 10%;
padding: 5px 5px;

}

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<title>Hull Daily News</title>
</head>
<body>
<webhead>
<img class="webheadlogo" src="logo1.png" alt=".logo">
<img class="webheadimg" src="Webhead.jpg" alt=".Webhead" />


</webhead>


<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="website.html">Home</a>
<li><a href="breakingnews.html">Breaking News</a></li>
<li><a href="Sport.html">Sport</a></li>
<li><a href="Hulltoday.html">Hull Today</a></li>
<li><a href="Property.html">Property</a></li>
<li><a href="Social.html">Social Media</a></li>
<li><a href="Music.html">Music</a></li>
<li><a href="Reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
<li><a href="Movies.html">Movies</a></li>
<li><a href="Weather.html">Weather</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="body1">
Text Box
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes to you css and removed the break tag between ul and textbox. Try this css, I think it is doing what you are looking for.

```css
body {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
 
}

.body1 {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 80vw;
    max-width: 72.6vw;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top:0px;
    max-font-size:16px; 
    position:relative;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    
}

    
.webheadimg {
width:96vw;
height:auto;
    max-width:96vw;
    max-height:auto;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    overflow:hidden;
margin-left:1vw;

    }    
#menu {
    width: 21.4vw;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1vw;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 1vw;
    background-color: #CA2A2A;
    border-radius: 0px;
    max-width: 96vw;
 float:left;
    
}
#menu ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 0.5vw 0vw;
    margin: 0px;
}
#menu li { 
    display: block; 
 

}
#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0.5vw 0.5vw 0.5vw 0.5vw;
 font-size: 3vw;
 display:block;
    
}
#menu a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;

}
.webheadlogo {
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;
margin-left: 1vw;
float:left;
height: auto;
width: 10%;
padding: 5px 5px;

}

}
```

```html
<body>
<div>
<img class="webheadlogo" src="logo1.png" alt=".logo">
<img class="webheadimg" src="Webhead.jpg" alt=".Webhead" />

</div>
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="website.html">Home</a>
<li><a href="breakingnews.html">Breaking News</a></li>
<li><a href="Sport.html">Sport</a></li>
<li><a href="Hulltoday.html">Hull Today</a></li>
<li><a href="Property.html">Property</a></li>
<li><a href="Social.html">Social Media</a></li>
<li><a href="Music.html">Music</a></li>
<li><a href="Reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
<li><a href="Movies.html">Movies</a></li>
<li><a href="Weather.html">Weather</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="body1">
Text Box
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: it works until it goes below 700px for me, any idea why?

Comment: On my local machine it works even below 700px.. can you post the screenshot for below 700px pointing what is wrong it?